# how to add new line between header and data in flat file using informatica?

Tags: informatica

how to add new line between header and data in flat file using informatica?

below is the example.

current:

```
ID NAME AGE
1 RAJA 28
2 JOHN 29
3 JOE 2O
```

EXPECTED:

```
ID NAME AGE


1 RAJA 28
2 JOHN 29
3 JOE 20
```

Comment: They seem the same to me..

Comment: @sagi now update plz check

Answer (score 0):

Use the Header Command option in session to generate the header row and newlines

e.g. `echo ID NAME AGE;echo;echo`

Comment: its not working :( from unix box its working but from informatica header comment its not working

Comment: am getting output like(-e ID NAME AGE/n/n )

Comment: use multiple 'echo's like this: `echo ID NAME AGE;echo;echo`. This should work.

Comment: Working as expected. Thank U Samik :) U r great

Answer (score 0):

Use a command task in a workflow or post command in a session and provide the below unix script,

```
awk 'NR==2{print ""} {print}' FileName > FileName
```

This will insert a blank line next to the header line in a file